# Can someone please explain me how this type of recursion works?

Tags: c, recursion

I came across this problem in recursion. I can't figure out how it works. I understand the basics of recursion but this totally confuses me. Please help.

```
main() { 
    foo(3); 
}

void foo(int x) {
    if (x >= 1) {
        foo(--x);
        printf("%d", x);
        foo(--x);
    }
}
```

I thought this program wouldn't print anything but it prints **0120** .

Doesn't the first call to foo(--3) i.e foo(2) jump to the beginning of the function and recur till 3 decrements to 0?

*Please explain how this works.*

Comment: `x` is being passed by value, not by reference. `--x` in other calls do not affect the current call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first call to `foo()` can be explained using a recursion tree:

```
  prints (in reverse order)

    2 <----------  foo(3)
                  /      \
    1 <----- foo(2)       foo(1) -----> 0
             /   \        /     \
    0 <-- foo(1) foo(0)  foo(0)  foo(-1)
         /    \ 
      foo(0)   foo(-1)
```

First, the left sub-tree will be evaluated and will print `012` and then the right sub-tree will be evaluated and will print `0`. Finally you get the output:

```
0120
```

Comment: Does this recursion tree principle apply to all forms of recursion? I mean what would be the case if foo(3) calls more than 2 functions?

Comment: @Tania; For simple recursion you can draw but for complex, it would be more complex.

Comment: Okay but Is there any other defined way to parse complex recursions? Apart from this techniques. Example, with the use of stacks? In the same problem if foo(4) is passed, i get a 19 digit output.

Comment: @Tania; Read this: [Tracing Recursive Functions](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/trace-recursion.html). This would be helpful.

Comment: I tried reading through the article but it was a bit complicated to me.I didn't get their box and circle notation. Can you please explain how foo(4) works in the same way? I tried drawing a tree and tracing the result but ended up getting 3012000 as the answer, which is wrong.

Comment: @haccks: I have question, Does that 2nd `foo(--x)` executing?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak; Why not? Its like tree traversal.

Comment: @haccks: How? I am not understanding how the recursion is working here in a loop. Sorry, but this is the fact I am completely could not able to understand.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak; I can't explain any better than I already explained in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

So foo(3) is:

```
foo(2)
print 2
foo(1)
```

And foo(2) is:

```
foo(1)
print 1
foo(0)
```

And foo(1) is:

```
foo(0)
print 0
foo(-1)
```

Now foo(0) and foo(-1) are no-ops, so foo(1) is:

```
print 0
```

Whence foo(2) is:

```
print 0
print 1
```

And foo(3) is:

```
print 0
print 1
print 2
print 0
```

This gives you the observed output.

Answer (score 1):

this is the expected output. next function calls are pushed to the stack and printf statement won't be executed until previous function call returns.

```
foo(3) --> foo(2) --> foo(1) --> foo(0)
```

now x is not >=1, so no more function calls and foo(0) is popped of stack. printf statement from foo(1) is executed and 0 (since x value was decremented) goes to stdout. another foo() call :

```
foo(3) --> foo(2) --> foo(1) --> foo(-1)
                             //  ^^ second foo() call from foo(1)
```

current output:

```
0
```

this does nothing. foo(-1) and foo(1) are popped of stack.
now printf is called from foo(2) and 1 goes to stdout.

call foo(0).

```
foo(3) --> foo(2) --> foo(0)
                  //  ^^ second foo() call from foo(2)
```

current output:

```
01
```

foo(0) does nothing, then pop foo(0) and foo(2) of the stack.

now we're in foo(3). print 2 and call foo(1).

```
foo(3) --> foo(1)
       //  ^^ second foo() call from foo(3)
```

current output:

```
012
```

foo(1) calls foo(0) then prints 0 and then calls foo(-1). now all remaining foo's are popped of the stack and you got 0120 on output.

@haccks - see this program. there are calls to foo(-1).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int);

int main() { 
    foo(3); 
    return 0;
}

void foo(int x) {
    if (x >= 1) {
        printf("executing foo with x = %d\n",x-1);
        foo(--x);
        printf("original output: %d\n", x);
        printf("executing foo with x = %d\n",x-1);
        foo(--x);
    }
}
```

output:

```
executing foo with x = 2
executing foo with x = 1
executing foo with x = 0
original output: 0
executing foo with x = -1
original output: 1
executing foo with x = 0
original output: 2
executing foo with x = 1
executing foo with x = 0
original output: 0
executing foo with x = -1
```

Comment: really? i thought that in ``foo(1)`` you are already inside an if statement, and after ``foo(0)`` returns, execute printf and then call ``foo(-1)``.

Comment: My mistake. Yes I was wrong. Removing my downvote. But still your explanation is not clear.

Comment: I don't get the stack part of your explanation. Can you please explain it again, forgetting the outputs of each calls? I just need to know how the functions are pushed into the stack and popped out.