# understanding this recursive function

Tags: c++, c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void e(int );      
int main( ) 
{   
    int a;    
    a=3;    
    e(a); 
    return 0;
}    

void e(int n)  
{    
    if(n>0)   
    {
        e(n-1); 
        n = n-1;     
        printf("%d" , n);      
        e(n-1);  
        n = n-1; 
    }    
}
```

I do not understand how this evaluates to 0120, because i thought if it was 0 the if statement would not run... i know i'm not great at coding but was wondering if someone could explain how it outputs 0120.

Comment: Did you see the line `n = n-1;` right above where it's printed?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want as output?

Comment: I dont want an output im trying to understand why 0120 is the output.

Comment: Run through the code line by line either with a debugger or by hand (it's simple enough) to understand it easier.

Comment: @ArtRoss Use a pen and paper, and run through the code.

Comment: @vsoftco i have many times, I just don't fully understand how it can go from 0 to 1 if i'm only subtracting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone please explain me how this type of recursion works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164465/can-someone-please-explain-me-how-this-type-of-recursion-works)

Comment: Run it through again.

Comment: @ArtRoss Remember that you first call the function, THEN display the value. Recursive calls stack up.

Comment: I mean, it's obviously homework or a book/site exercise, you won't get a full, written explanation from us, ready to copypasta into an answer...

Comment: The easiest and safest way, by far, is to step through this code with your debugger, inspect the vars at each line and make notes of what is happening.  Rinse/repeat until you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple programs like this can be 'augmented' with a few prints for understanding.

Your original:

```
// original
void e(int n)
{
   if(n>0)
   {
      e(n-1);
      n = n-1;
      printf("%d" , n);
      e(n-1);
      n = n-1;
   }
}
```

and it's output is the same  (even when compiled with c++)

```
// 0120
```

Here is very similar recursive code with a couple more prints

```
// with debug prints
void e2(int n, std::stringstream& ss)
{
   static size_t seq = 0;
   std::cout << "seq=" << ++seq << " e2() " << "  n=" << n << std::endl; // invocation sequence
   if(n>0)
   {
      e2(n-1, ss);
      n = n-1;
      ss << "n= " << n << " " << std::flush;
      e2(n-1, ss);
      n = n-1;
   }
   else
      std::cout << "seq=" << seq << " e2()   else " << n << std::endl;
}
```

And the invocation used:

```
int t267(int argc0)
{
   std::cout << "argc0: " << argc0 << std::endl << std::endl;

   int a = 3;

   std::cout << "\ne()----------------------------" << std::endl;
   e(a);

   std::cout << "\ne2()----------------------------" << std::endl;
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "e2: " << std::endl;
   e2(a, ss);
   std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "\n----------------------------" << std::endl;

   return(0);

} // int t267(void)
```

Some intermediate outputs:

```
seq=1 e2()   n=3
seq=2 e2()   n=2
seq=3 e2()   n=1
seq=4 e2()   n=0
seq=4 e2()   else 0
seq=5 e2()   n=-1
seq=5 e2()   else -1
seq=6 e2()   n=0
seq=6 e2()   else 0
seq=7 e2()   n=1
seq=8 e2()   n=0
seq=8 e2()   else 0
seq=9 e2()   n=-1
seq=9 e2()   else -1
```

The ss captures all the n= x to report them in a simpler, fashion and not interleaved amongst the debug cout's.  The output from ss:

```
n= 0 n= 1 n= 2 n= 0
```

Note: this shows the same digit sequence as the original

It also shows 9 recursion calls occurred. (seq=9)
Is that what you expected?

... debug printing can often provide enough info to observe and repair coding errors, too.

Next try a=0, or 1, or 2, or 4, ... etc.
And try adding additional prints.
Practice.

And review the intermediate outputs step by step to see how it works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the recursive function you must first understand recursion :)
seriously though go read the wikipedia page and any other articles you can find.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

The import thing to remember here is that every recursive call to e increases your call stack, and once you return you pop the last frame off your call stack and **return to where you last called e**.

Here are the steps of what actually happens in your case and why it does what it does. A debugger will also let you do this walk through :)

1. e gets called with 3
2. 3 > 0 so we call e with 3 - 1 (2)
3. 2 > 0 so we call e with 2 - 1 (1)
4. 1 > 0 so we call e with 1 - 1 (0)
5. 0 is not > 0 so we return back to when int n = 1
6. we now set n = n - 1 so n = 0
7. print n (prints 0)
8. call e with 0 - 1 (-1) -> this just returns
9. Set n = n - 1 and return to when n = 2
10. set n = n - 1 so n = 1
11. print n (prints 1)
12. call e with n - 1 (0) -> this just returns
13. set n = n - 1 and return to when n = 3
14. set n = n - 1 so n = 2
15. print n (prints 2)
16. call e with n - 1 (1)
17. 1 > 0 so call e with n - 1 (0) -> this just returns
18. set n = n - 1 (0)
19. print n (prints 0)
20. call e with n - 1 (-1) -> this just returns
21. set n = n - 1 and return again to when n = 3 (the original function call)
22. This is the end of our function call, we now return having printed 0120

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I miss something?